# Where the templ files are created in blob triggered azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, kudu

I am working on an Azure Function application on Windows Azure.
I have created a Blob triggered azure function that creats a file in temp folder. To get the path of temporary folder to create the temporary file I am using following code block:

```
string TempFolderLocation = Path.GetTempPath();
string TempFileName = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".txt";
string TempFilePath = Path.Combine(TempFolderLocation, TempFileName);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(TempFilePath, "This is the time log : " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

I get the path "D:\local\Temp\" as result of Path.GetTempPath().

I am not getting any error when above code gates executed But when I take KUDU of my azure function application, there is no files created in folder "D:\local\Temp\".

So my questions are:

1. Is execution of blob triggered azure function happening at different
   location then KUDU?
2. Is the execution time temp folder is different then the actual?
3. Where can I see those temp files?

Comment: How do you host your Azure Function App ? Is it either Consumption plan or App Service plan?

Comment: @SzymonTomczyk, It is hosted in AppService plan.

Answer (score 0):

The azure function doesn't share the temp storage with kudu (and there is a legacy flag to force them to share).

Check "Temporary files" section here:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files

> Another important note is that the Main site and the scm site do not
>   share temp files. So if you write some files there from your site, you
>   will not see them from Kudu Console (and vice versa). You can make
>   them use the same temp space if you disable separation (via
>   WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION). But note that this is a legacy flag,
>   and its use is not recommended/supported.